# Do I need a transit visa to morocco

Tags: transit-visas, morocco, libyan-citizens, cmn

I am a Libyan national travelling through Casablanca to Montreal.  I have a 3-hour transit in Casablanca.  Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

Royal Air Maroc, among others, has a web page which lets you look up [health and visa requirements](https://www.royalairmaroc.com/int-en/Practical-Guide/Visas-and-Vaccinations/Trip-Information) in Timatic, the database most international airlines use to check such requirements.

For a Libyan national departing Libya enroute to Canada via Morocco, a transit visa is not required provided that

- You hold a confirmed onward ticket
- You transit on the same calendar day
- You remain in the international transit area at CMN (i.e. do not go through immigration processing to enter Morocco itself)